# Spring Boot and Togglz: Catching feature activation time and do some action when feature became active

Tags: java, spring-boot, togglz

I have feature togglz in my spring boot application. There are some features which are successfully work for the moment. So now I need to do some operation right in the time when one of my feature is activated.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

By using Spring Scheduling you can resolve your problem.

step 1:  Enable scheduling for this annotation @EnableScheduling  at class level

step 2: You can use any pattern like, hourly, minute, fixed delay,..etc.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * MON-FRI")`enter code here`
void checTogglzk() {
   // ...
 }
```

Comment: Not really what I want to do. I need to call my method only once at day when my feature actually will be activated.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement Custom ActivationStrategy and call your method within it.
Example how to do it in toggz doc: https://www.togglz.org/documentation/activation-strategies.html